# Destructuring with unstated.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state, unstated

I have this Unstated container:

```
import { Container } from 'unstated';
import axios from 'axios';

export default class CurrenciesContainer extends Container {
  state = { currencies: null };
  async fetch() {
    const { data: currencies } = await axios.get('http://localhost:8080/get-currencies');
    this.setState({ currencies });
  }
}
```

And this function that utilises it:

```
static renderCurrencies() {
  return (
    <Subscribe to={[CurrenciesContainer]}>
      {(currencies) => {
        if (!currencies.state.currencies) {
          currencies.fetch();
        }
        return <small>Currencies: {currencies.state.currencies}</small>;
      }}
    </Subscribe>
  );
}
```

I wanted to try and destructure the params coming into the `<Subscribe>` like so:

```
static renderCurrencies() {
  return (
    <Subscribe to={[CurrenciesContainer]}>
      {({ state, fetch }) => {
        if (!state.currencies) {
          fetch();
        }
        return <small>Currencies: {state.currencies}</small>;
      }}
    </Subscribe>
  );
}
```

But this breaks with `Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: this.setState is not a function`

Clearly it's not binding properly but I'm not sure why the destructuring of the function would change its binding. Anyone able to offer an explanation/way of doing it like this? Thanks!

Comment: What happens if you use `({ state, fetch } = state.currencies) => { ... }`?

Comment: @Matt have a look at my answer

Comment: @AndrewHill Not sure what you mean - the fetch function isn't inside `state.currencies` so it can't be destructured from there...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace `async fetch() {}` with `fetch = async () => {}` to achieve the correct binding.

Try this in your Unstated container:

```
import { Container } from 'unstated';
import axios from 'axios';

export default class CurrenciesContainer extends Container {
  state = { currencies: null };
  fetch = async () => {
    const { data: currencies } = await axios.get('http://localhost:8080/get-currencies');
    this.setState({ currencies });
 }
}
```

Comment: Yeah you're right, `fetch = async () => {` does the trick (although I'm not sure why you modified the code inside the function...?) Thanks

Comment: as both the codes does same thing , but your code looks much cleaner, thanks for the edit